How can I center a trimesh window on screen?
I have started to work with Python's trimesh package and the first thing I want to do is to set the size of the graphics window and its position on the screen.
I figured out how to resize the graphics window, as the simple code below (from https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/main/examples/colors.ipynb) shows:
import trimesh

# The XAML file is found at https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/main/models/machinist.XAML
mesh = trimesh.load("machinist.XAML", process=False)
mesh.visual.kind
# Resolution is an undocumated argument - I had to figure it out myself
mesh.show(resolution=(600,600))

But I also want to center the mesh window on screen. Does anyone know how?

After looking through the classes and methods for a quite a while, I finally found a solution.
The show method in the Scene class accepts a SceneViewer class as its viewer parameter (which is the default viewer, unless in a notebook)
The SceneViewer itself inherits from the pyglet.window.Window, which does have a set_location method. So, I ended up creating a custom class CenteredSceneViewer that centers itself by calculating the x and y coordinates of the centered window and invoking the set_location:
import trimesh
from trimesh.viewer.windowed import SceneViewer
from pyglet.canvas import Display

# A SceneViewer that will center itself on the screen
class CenteredSceneViewer(SceneViewer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get the screen resolution
        self.resolution = kwargs.get("resolution", (600, 600))
        display = Display()
        screen = display.get_default_screen()
        self.screen_width = screen.width
        self.screen_height = screen.height

        # We only need to center once
        self.centered = False

        super(CenteredSceneViewer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def dispatch_event(self, *args):
        if not self.centered:
            # Calculate the position to center the window
            window_x = (self.screen_width - self.resolution[0]) // 2
            window_y = (self.screen_height - self.resolution[1]) // 2

            # Set the location of the window
            self.set_location(window_x, window_y)
            self.centered = True

        super(CenteredSceneViewer, self).dispatch_event(*args)


mesh = trimesh.load("machinist.XAML", process=False)
mesh.show(viewer=CenteredSceneViewer, resolution=(600, 600))


import trimesh
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from trimesh.viewer import windowed

# Load the mesh
mesh = trimesh.load("machinist.XAML", process=False)

# Create a QApplication (required for all PyQt5 applications)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create a main window to hold the mesh viewer
main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

# Set the resolution of the mesh window
resolution = (600, 600)

# Calculate the center position of the screen
screen_geometry = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
x = (screen_geometry.width() - resolution[0]) // 2
y = (screen_geometry.height() - resolution[1]) // 2

# Set the size and position of the window
main_window.setGeometry(x, y, resolution[0], resolution[1])

# Create a trimesh viewer and set it as the central widget
mesh_viewer = windowed.SceneViewer(mesh, resolution=resolution)
main_window.setCentralWidget(mesh_viewer.window)

# Show the window
main_window.show()

# Start the application's event loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())


BTW, I can't verify the correctness of your solution because I don't have PyQt5 installed. Yet, I already upvoted your answer just because you came up with one.  And this is better than no answer at all.

Hi. I have installed PyQt5 and tried your code. The line mesh_viewer = windowed.SceneViewer(mesh, resolution=resolution) raises "AttributeError: 'Trimesh' object has no attribute 'camera_transform'".

Please explain what problem you saw with the original code, and try to repair the code from the original question if possible.  When you just paste a bunch of code without explanation, especially when it is not the original code, it is difficult to see what you think may be the problem.

@PoDuck, what do you mean by "what problem you saw with the original code"? The AttributeError and the code line that produced it are not enough for you? Or do you expect me to debug the code line that produced the error and find out what is the problem? This is the task of the coder.

Apostolos, I was speaking to user27047111.  I was going through evaluating first answers of people, and came across this.  This answer is subpar, and I was giving advice for user27047111 to make it better.  I know nothing about Trimesh, but I did look for 'camera_transform' in the code on github, and it is a property of 'Scene', not 'Trimesh' directly.  I suspect this answer was AI generated, because that is a common mistake AI algorithms make, and no explanation is common with those kinds of answers also.

I see, @PoDuck. So maybe it is better to use member names in your comments, as I do. Esp. when your comment is not directy below the member name in question. As for your research on the problem,  despite knowing nothing about Trimesh (!), that's fine, but this is supposed  to be the responsibility and task of the poster of the code, who presented it as a "solution",  which is proved to be untested. And I consider this a much bigger mistake than a mistake in the code itself.

I guess I assumed that since nothing in the comment pertained to anything you said, it would be obvious I wasn't talking to you.  When I am evaluating first answers, I'm not supposed to determine if the answer is correct or not, but that the answer is a quality answer.  This answer was not a quality answer, and since it was his first answer, I was giving the person the information they need to make it better.

There isn't a direct way to position or center the window on the screen through trimesh.
You can use pyglet or PyQt5 with trimesh to achive your requirment
If you use pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=600, height=600, caption="Trimesh Viewer")
screen = pyglet.canvas.get_display().get_default_screen()
window.set_location((screen.width - window.width) // 2, (screen.height - window.height) // 2)

If you use PyQt5
screen = QApplication.primaryScreen().geometry()
x = (screen.width() - self.width()) // 2
y = (screen.height() - self.height()) // 2
self.setGeometry(x, y, self.width(), self.height())

Output the show PyQt5
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mesh = trimesh.load("machinist.XAML", process=False)
window = MeshWindow(mesh)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

In the pyglet
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    mesh.show()

pyglet.app.run()

Output


OK, but the code I presented uses `mesh.show()' to display the model, which has special features and uses special interactive keys. How will a pyglet window fit in or be combined with all this?  Can you create a code with such a combination using the very simple Trimesh code I presented?

I have updated the code , you can use documentation regarding library you use to output the that you want , In pyglet you can modify according to your update eg: pyglet.window.Window like wise

Have you tried this code @Saranka?  I have. A huge window with the XAML model kept on popping up and a dozen of python.exe instances were opened, to a point that the Windows system has been stalled! I was almost ready to reboot my PC, but I managed to hit Ctrl-Break a dozen or more times to abort all those python.exe instances! That was really terrifying, Saranka. And I have seen quite a few terrifying things in my  40-year programming life!

I Just gave you example of how you can approach not exact soultion

you may get an infinite loop if you didnt convert it to support format . Eg : will get an error like ImportError: no graph engines available! continually. Normally XMAL Files are not very well support by trimesh. if you can covert it to STL, OBJ, or GLTF some of this it maybe load without an issue

OK, Sasanka. Thanks.

This is obviously wrong. mesh.draw creates a pyglet window, You are creating a different pyglet window, and on each redraw you are calling mesh.draw to create another window!
